# Ola, no tkinter como pegar o valor da soma gerada por numeros eleatorios e comparar com a entrada do usuario?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange, uniform

window = Tk() 
window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app") 
window.geometry('800x600')

lbl1 = Label(window, text="00", font=("Arial Bold", 50)) 
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl2 = Label(window, text="00", font=("Arial Bold", 50)) 
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=1)
lbl3 = Label(window, text="+", font=("Arial Bold", 50)) 
lbl3.grid(column=3, row=0)
resposta = Entry(window,width=4, font=("Arial Bold", 50)) 
resposta.grid(column=0, row=2)

def proxima():
    a = randrange(10, 99) #faixa de inteiro
    b = randrange(10, 99) #faixa de inteiro
    lbl1.configure(text= str(a))
    lbl2.configure(text= str(b))
    soma = a+b
    print(soma)

def calculo():  
    print(soma) 
    if resposta.get() == soma:
        print("Acertou")
    else:
        print("Errou...")

btn = Button(window, text="Proxima", command=proxima)
btn.grid(column=0, row=3)
btn2 = Button(window, text="Calcular", command=calculo)
btn2.grid(column=0, row=4)
window.mainloop()
```

Relacionar o item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara. O Tkinter **não tem nada a ver** com soma de números, ele é somente uma interface gráfica visual para o usuário interagir. A parte de somar números aleatórios e comparar, você tem que fazer em **python** mesmo, e não em tkinter.

Além disso você esqueceu de colocar o erro completo que está recebendo quando executa o seu código. Fica muito mais fácil ver o problema quando tem o erro completo. Sugiro [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/369069/edit) a pergunta e acrescentar informações para que ela fique mais clara.

---

Quanto à resposta, parece que você está usando duas variáveis chamadas `soma`; uma dentro da função `proxima` e outra dentro da função `resposta`.

Em python as variáveis ficam presas ao escopo em que elas foram criadas; se você quiser acessar uma variável que está em outro escopo, é preciso fazer isso manualmente, e cada função cria um escopo de variáveis.

Uma forma direta de resolver seria passar a variável `soma` para o escopo global.

```
def proxima():
    global soma
    # ... restante da função continua igual
```

Comment: Valeu amigo! Mesmo sem entender você me deu a resposta que precisava, "global soma", funcionou da forma que queria!